# PHPExcel Library in a while loop , cause the increasing of memory?

Tags: php

the function is like following:

```
public function   getFile($fileFullPath){
               echo round(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024,2).'MB'.PHP_EOL;
        $PHPReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($fileFullPath);
        if(! $PHPReader){
            return false;
        }
        $PHPExcel = $PHPReader->load($fileFullPath);
        $currentSheet = $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
                 return $currentSheet
}
```

the function is called by a while loop . and when running the program, the memory is increase constantly . the output info like this :

```
➜  crontab git:(f_*****) ✗ php worker.php program_name.php

1.64MB
8MB
10.56MB
12.99MB
15.68MB
18.11MB
20.54MB
23.47MB
25.91MB
28.34MB
30.77MB
```

is anyone  familiar with the  PHPExcel Library, and tell me how can I init the cache between every while loop finaly stoping the increase of the memory using.

Comment: What while loop?

Comment: Are you adding the result of this function (its return value) to an array or something like that? If you do this many times, you will run out of memory. Also please show us your while-loop.

Comment: the while loop just  some other  code that  not  relate  the phpexcel.   just  like :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this?

```
$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets(); 
unset($objPHPExcel);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for yours concern.  I have found out the solution.  In every loop of the while .  I delete the cache of the sheet like :

```
while(true){
   $currentSheet = $this->getFile($fullPath);
   ...  //do anything with $currentSheet;
   $currentSheet->disconnectWorksheets();   // drop the cache;
}
```

Through the disconnectWorksheets  of the PHPlibrary.  It  drop  the cache of cells.  so the memory stop increasing.